# Having error in gradle in running flutter app in vscode

Tags: java, android, gradle, visual-studio-code

When running my created app from vscode to the actual android phone using vysor I get this error:

```
> Launching lib\main.dart on RMX2020 in debug mode...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timeout of 120000 reached waiting for exclusive access to file: C:\Users\Rhea Baja\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-5.6.2-all\9st6wgf78h16so49nn74lgtbb\gradle-5.6.2-all.zip
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:61)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timeout of 120000 reached waiting for exclusive access to file: C:\Users\Rhea Baja\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-5.6.2-all\9st6wgf78h16so49nn74lgtbb\gradle-5.6.2-all.zip
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:61)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

[Here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UujNm.png)

Comment: Please have a look at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/56552. Try it and see if the error goes away.

Answer (score 0):

You need a stable internet connection for downloading some stuffs.
It will automatically download and install bellow things and will run your app:

```
    Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.2 in C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\licenses
License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.2 accepted.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.2 (revision: 29.0.2)".
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.2 (revision: 29.0.2)" ready.
Installing Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.2 in C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\29.0.2
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.2 (revision: 29.0.2)" complete.
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.2 (revision: 29.0.2)" finished.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 30 in C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\licenses
License for package Android SDK Platform 30 accepted.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform 30 (revision: 3)".
"Install Android SDK Platform 30 (revision: 3)" ready.
Installing Android SDK Platform 30 in C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-30   
"Install Android SDK Platform 30 (revision: 3)" complete.
"Install Android SDK Platform 30 (revision: 3)" finished.
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                            810.6s
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...              1,297ms
W/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate( 7450): A splash screen was provided to Flutter, but this is deprecated. See flutter.dev/go/android-splash-migration for migration steps.
Syncing files to device sdk gphone x86...                          746ms
```